# JavaScript условия RU или EN

Tags: javascript, jquery

Такой вопрос. Как сделать кнопку с двумя файлами. Открытие в новом окне about:blank.

То есть есть 2 файла `EN-blank.php` и `RU-blank.php`

Как сделать условие, чтоб при загрузке страницы, чекался язык браузера функцией:

```
var language = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

и если ru, то запускать `RU-blank.php` при нажатии на кнопку если en язык браузера, то `EN-blank.php`, при том что ссылка/кнопка на странице одна.

Две кнопки или ссылки мне не нужны.

Comment: А что делать, если другой язык?

Comment: en запускать
Условие я сам составлю. мне нужна функция запуска файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button onclick="checkLang();">Перейти на подходящий язык</button>

function checkLang()
{
    var lang = (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage).slice(0, 2); 
    window.open('lang/' + (lang == 'ru' ? 'RU' : 'EN') + '-blank.php', '_blank', "width=200,height=100");
}
```

Comment: не открывается(

Comment: @SazNik, попытайтесь теперь. Изменил ответ.

Comment: нечего((( просто обновляет и все(

Comment: @SazNik, но так и должно быть, если у вас уже открыта RU-blank.php, к примеру. Закройте её и затем нажмите на кнопку.

Comment: не открыта нечего. открыт один index.php и в нем одна кнопка и функция эта.

Comment: у меня эти 2 файла идут в папке lang

Comment: все разобрался. вот только открывает в новой вкладке( а надо в новом окне(

Comment: ну а какими средствами это можно сделать?

Comment: само окно я открывал такое, но пустое(((

Comment: ну я же само окно открывал же) правда пустое совсем(

Comment: @SazNik, если пустое, то значит страница PHP либо имеет ошибку, либо не выдаёт ничего. Как вы это окно открывали?

Comment: в том то и подвох) отдельно открывалась)

Comment: @SazNik, мне тут подсказали, что и новое окно можно открыть, если указать 3-ий параметр. Изменил ответ.

Comment: Видел) ща попробую)

Comment: да) работает) всем спасибо огромное за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понял вопрос, и в новой вкладке должна открываться страничка `(EN|RU)-blank.php` по клику на элементе,  то в обработчике клика достаточно написать:

```
var lang = (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage).slice(0, 2); 
if (lang != 'ru')
  lang = 'en'; 
window.open(lang + '-blank.php', '_blank');
```

Регистр первых двух символов имени файла в URL не имеет значения, но если хочется заглавные - просто добавьте `.toUpperCase()`.

[<kbd>`Демо на JS Bin`</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/sewiwuxufi/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: в обработчики клика я так понимаю добавить функцию к вашему скрипту и добавить её к обработчику? простите в js новичок....

Comment: @SazNik, я не уверен что верно понимаю сленг "добавить функцию к скрипту", поэтому дополнил ответ ссылкой на демо - посмотрите, попробуйте (здесь на SO открытие новой вкладки из сниппета не выполняется - наверное, заблокировали специально).

Comment: не работает ссылка на демо

Comment: @SazNik, работает :) Попробуйте в адресную строку браузера вставить ссылку: `http://jsbin.com/sewiwuxufi/edit?html,js,output`

Comment: страница не найдена

Comment: @SazNik, хм... тогда это уже к провайдеру/роскомнадзору :) Если на пальцах показать, то код нужно поместить `yourElement.addEventListener('click', () => {  >>сюда<< });`.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzWYmK

Answer (score 0):

Заранее прошу прощения, комментировать пока не могу.
Откроется новое окно, если добавить к методу параметры (размер, расположение), например:

```
window.open('lang/' + (lang == 'ru' ? 'RU' : 'EN') + '-blank.php', '_blank', 'width=200,height=100' );
```

Comment: благо дарю за подсказку! Добавил в ответ.